# Access fragment method from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've a fragment register. this one has a view pager inside. I need every page to put a data into register hashmap variable . this what i've tried ..

this is a method that i want to access from every pages

```
public void addData(String key, String data){
     Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

i've tried like :

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
fragment = (ArtistRegister)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.asd);
fragment.addData("asd", asd);
```

but it always return null pointer ..

Comment: So basically, you need to call method from `ViewPager` fragment from `ViewPager` children?

Comment: i need to call method from fragment parent. in this case fragment that hold a viewpager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First solution:**

```
ArtistRegister artistRegister = ((ArtistRegister) getParentFragment());
artistRegister.addData("asd", "asd");
```

**Second solution:**

Create `interface` and pass it as argument for `PagerAdapter` constructor.

**EDIT:**

OP used `getFragmentManager()` instead of `getChildFragmentManager()` to initialize adapter, so he was constantly getting `NullPointerExpception`

Comment: I wonder what you did wrong, because first solution should work. What errors did you have?

Comment: always get unreachable statement in get item fragmentpageradapter

Comment: unreachable statement is result of first or second solution?

Comment: this one is parent fragment containts viewpager , ive inner class adapter for viewpager. http://pastebin.com/gxvgMBcj . and this one is a fragment inside viewpager http://pastebin.com/HbMzmhnC

Comment: Remove `return new UserInfo(ri);` from `getItem`. Change `return UserInfo.newInstance(0, "User Info");` to `return UserInfo.newInstance(0, "User Info", ri);` Change `public static UserInfo newInstance(int page, String title)` to `public static UserInfo newInstance(int page, String title, RegisterInterface ri)` and remove `static` from all RegisterInterface variables. And remember **don't use `static` where it's not needed**

Comment: same error E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.flux.vibecast.Fragment.UserInfo$1.afterTextChanged(UserInfo.java:69)

Comment: Are you sure that `bandName` variable is not null ? Also remove `static` from `public static class StepAdapter`

Comment: OK, I have started checking your code line by line. Why did you use `getFragmentManager()` here in line `stepAdapter = new StepAdapter(getFragmentManager(), ri);` ? You are supposed to change it to `stepAdapter = new StepAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), ri);` and then use my first solution. It must work.

Comment: it's work .. i did'nt notice that i use getFragmentmanager() . Thanks man , you rock.

Comment: That's why it's better to add more code to question, because problem could lie somewhere else :)